# How to ignore files with PhpStorm and Git?

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm, gitignore

I am not able to ignore files which are already under version control.

The "Ignore..." entry is disabled:

[image]

1st question: Why is it disabled?

2nd: How to add files afterwards to git ignore?

Thanks a lot!

### Edit

**PhpStorm** says: "This option is only available if a file under the Unversioned Files node is selected. Use this option to ignore the selected file if you want to leave it unversioned."

*(Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/local-changes-tab.html)*

But sometimes you may have files for an initial commit, then add it to git ignore to allow local changes (for local development) while not committing / pushing this file to any repo anymore.

### Edit 2

Another way I handle this nowadays is to add the changes with credentials to a **Changelist** which is not committed:

[image]

Comment: Which version of phpstorm do you use?

Comment: PhpStorm 2016.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comments I think what you really need here is lock file feature, that exists (as far as I know) **only** on gitlab. But... this requires central server so it's actually against git main idea.

In most cases - as Stony said - you should create template file like `config.template.php` or `config.dev.php`, add `config.php` to .gitignore and make each developer rename/recreate config.php.

Another way would be to create deploy script with transformation instructions that'll automatically adjust paths inside config file, maybe automatically deploy entire application, and run it at each deploy.

Or simply exclude config file every time you commit changes.

Answer (score 18):

It make no sense to ignore files that are already in your version control. So you have to remove them first with:

```
git rm --cached filename
```

then that files exist locally but are removed from your repository. Then you can ignore that files.

Comment: The idea is: there is a config.php.
This file was initially committed and pushed.
A developer clones the repo to his local virtual enivronment and adjusts a path, exclusively for his local environment. This changes should not be committed and pushed to the repo / to the production server.
So in my opinion there is one reasonable solution:
config.php to git ignore (not versioned, not in repo); developers share their config.php with local VM adjustments and their is a special config.php with other settings on the server. Correctly? Thanks!

Comment: In most cases you should ignore that config.php file and make a file like config.template.php and then check that file in. Every environment or developer can copy that file and use it. It's not such a good idea to checkin your passwords and settings to your repository.

Answer (score 8):

For the first question, as you found in the link.

For the second question, if you want to ignore a file which has already version controlled by git, you should use git command to do that:

1. In the local repo, add the file name in `.gitignore` file. If you don’t have `.gitignore`, you can use `touch .gitignore`.
2. `git rm --cached filename`.